# HashMap behaving weird

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        long sq = 16;
        int v = 8, u = 2;
        int ans = 0;
        map.put(u, map.getOrDefault(u, 0) + 1);
        ans += map.getOrDefault(sq/v, 0);
        
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

The answer should be clearly 1 but it outputs 0.
Any idea why it behaves like this?
Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`sq/v` divides `long` by `int`, so the result is a `long`, which is boxed to `Long` when passed to `map.getOrDefault(sq/v,0)`. You have no `Long` keys in your `Map`, so it returns the default value `0`.

If you change `sq` to `int`, the result of `sq/v` will also be `int`, and `map.getOrDefault(sq/v,0)` will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

**The map wants type java.lang.Integer as key**

Change to this:

```
ans += map.getOrDefault(Integer.valueOf((int) (sq/v)), 0);
```

**Note:** Primitive data type **int** will also work.

This will also work:

```
ans += map.getOrDefault((int) (sq/v), 0);
```